# Open file box hidden

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

With a Word file already open and maximized, I go to a minimized folder window containing word docs, and if I open a file that needs permissions, the dialog window remains hidden instead of popping in front like with excel files. It's annoying as I usually open several protected word docs in sequence. help please.

Answer (score 1):

Pressing Alt-Esc will cycle through all windows, bringing them to the front. This is not a permanent solution, but one that allows you to get to your dialog box when you need to.

Comment: Thanks. In MSExcel the dialog box pops in front. Why on earth didn't they make MSWord the same way!!! I tried to address Microsoft but couldn't reach someone to sugest the change.